# change value in nested em with li

Tags: jquery, dom

Stupid question - but cannot get my head around it right now..

Have:

```
<ul id='sortable'>
    <li draggable='true' class='draggable'><em id=1>1:</em> Drag me 1</li>
    <li draggable='true' class='draggable'><em id=2>2:</em> Drag me 2</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to do a sort on the two `<li>`'s and on change of sort - change the value in the `<em></em>` -is it possible or am I just too focused on the wrong path here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely possible. http://jsfiddle.net/earurv41/

```
$('#sortable').sortable({
    stop:function(){
        $(this).find('li').each(function(k, v){
            $(this).find('em').text((k + 1) + ':');
        });
    }
});
```

I took out the "draggable" stuff, but you can add it back if you have another use for it.

Comment: any idea how to create additional <ul><li></li></ul> elements and still keep the "sorting" (perhaps it should be in another question)

Comment: not sure what you mean by keeping the sorting - do you want the sorting on one of the ul's to copy to the others, or you want each one to be sorted separately? here's the latter with a nested ul too: http://jsfiddle.net/xw7dhjky/